# CSS Hue-Rotate animation to filter SVG?

Tags: css, animation, svg

Trying to add custom Hue-Rotate filter on SVG to animate paths?

Is their a way to clip the animation background on the SVG paths?

```
<svg id="example" class="hue">
<g id="main">
<path d="....."/>
<path d="....."/>
<path d="....."/>
</g>
</svg>


/* HUE Effect */
.hue {
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: inherit;
    color: #f35626;
    /*background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg ,#f35626 ,#feab3a);
    fill: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg ,#f35626 ,#feab3a); */
    filter: -linear-gradient(0deg ,#f35626 ,#feab3a);
}
@-webkit-keyframes hue {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: clipping is via clip-path or clip

Comment: @RobertLongson could you provide an example it doesn't seem to work on the site

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks